# Ember.js: find DOM element by binding / model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js, automated-tests, integration-testing

Angular's Protractor lets you [find an element](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) by various "angular properties", such as binding, model, repeater, etc.

```
<span>{{person.name}}</span>
<span ng-bind="person.email"></span>
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name"/>
```

then

```
// Find element with {{scopeVar}} syntax.
element(by.binding('person.name')).getText().then(function(name) {
  expect(name).toBe('Foo');
});

// Find element with ng-bind="scopeVar" syntax.
expect(element(by.binding('person.email')).getText()).toBe('foo@bar.com');

// Find by model.
var input = element(by.model('person.name'));
input.sendKeys('123');
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Foo123');
```

This is done by regular javascript in the clientside as seen [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js).

Is there something similar for Ember.js?

I'm talking about the `element(by.someLocator(...))` API.

Answer (score 0):

No. We use jQuery to find elements.